# Windows 10 Touch keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I am working on a winforms project, the project will only work in kiosk mode with touch controls.

I have textbox in one of the steps, I want to start the taskbar touch keyboard when I enter the textbox, I was able to start the virtual touch keybaord task but I want to use the docked version that fires from the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running *osk.exe*. Instead, run *tabtip.exe*. It is located under *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink* but you shouldn't need to specify the path.